# Xcode open an iOS project as macOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I have Xcode 12.2, I'm trying to open an iOS project, but xcode opens it as a macOS project. How to redefine the platform?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new ios target and delete the ones that you don't want.
Click the + button at the bottom of the Targets List.

[image]

Then select ios, filter by "app," and select the iOS app template target.

[image]

Once your new target is added, you can select the new target Scheme. The ios devices will be listed in that Scheme.